# How can I remember an action taken by a logged in user?

Tags: php

How can you make it so, that my website remember an action, taken by a user who is logged into my Wordpress website?

I would like to make a checkbox. A standard checkbox like these:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_checkbox

For example, if I select a checkbox, log out, and when I log in again, the checkbox should still be checked.

Hope someone can help! :-)

Comment: Your question is *very* broad, and thus hard to answer. What kind of action? Something in the front end, or in the back end? Related to a specific post? Stored for a specific user, or everyone? Related to the overall site? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/355582/edit) to let us know what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I will make a regular checkbox that I have referred to. Such a checkbox should be placed on one of my pages on my website.

What I can't figure out to do is that you should be able to set the checkbox to cheked. Next time you log in as a user on my website, you will see that the checkbox is still marked as cheked.

Basically I want to set my website to remember an action taken by a user. And yes, it is front-end.

Comment: You can store the checked or not state in user meta. You can read this in your template, so you can set up the checkbox with the correct state on page load; if you want to save the value as soon as it's changed you'll have to write some script to act when the box is changed (and e.g. not changed again within a second) and an API endpoint e.g. using admin-ajax for your script to call that saves the value.